# Which code is responsible to write auth.log?

Tags: kali-linux, logging

How to find the program which writes auth.log file in kali linux? I tried searching for that program but couldn't find it.

Comment: have you try to check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (wherever the file is located)?

Answer (score 0):

Many programs and subsystems write to it, like `systemd`, `cron`, your login manager which could be SDDM for Plasma DE, GDM for GNOME, PAM which is an authentication subsystem used by login shells and login managers.

Best to open it on your system and see for yourself.  All the log entries are prefixed by the program or subsystem that created the entry.

Even every time you use the `sudo` command, an entry is created there.